# Liquibase precondition MARK_RAN when succeding

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I have the following changeset in `Liquibase 3.6.3`:

```
- changeSet:
      id: random_id
      author: me
      comment: Remove the order table
      preConditions:
        - onFail: MARK_RAN
        - tableExists:
            tableName: order
      changes:
        - dropTable:
            cascadeConstraints: true
            tableName: order
```

When passing the changeset in my DB the tables exist. The changeset pass without complaining and removes the table as I expect. **HOWEVER**, the changeset is marked as **MARK_RAN** in the `databasechangelog`.

Well, I'm not sure if this is the normal behaviour but I would expect it to be **EXECUTED**

Comment: It's probably because of the table name "order" which is at least part of a reserved keyword in ANSI SQL. You might use orders instead but this is not the question here.

Comment: What version of mysql do you use?  I tested this changeset (but with xml configuration) and it works as expected, with EXECUTED in databasechangelog. I used MySQL version 5.7.25

Comment: Hey @htshame, I'm in 5.6